# Make Gmail default mail client without using Google Notifier

Tags: macos, google-chrome, apple-mail

When I File>Email page location in Google Chrome for Mac it opens a new email in OSX Mail.

It always used to open a new gmail.

How do I make it do this without using Google Notifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, opening Gmail in a recent version of Google Chrome should prompt you to set it as the default mail handler. What you can do is try to open the JavaScript console via <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, then paste the following:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s","Gmail");
```

Then press <kbd>↩</kbd>. Chrome should ask you to confirm the setting.

To check whether it succeeded, you can also use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). Download the `.dmg` file, double-click on the `.prefPane` file inside, and install the preference pane. Now under *System Preferences*, you can see *Default Apps* at the bottom. Make sure that for Email, and the `mailto` URL scheme, Chrome is set:

[image]

[image]

Comment: the console method comes back with underfined

Comment: It does for me as well, but except for that, does it work or not?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using? What happens when you run the [ad hoc test here](http://www.lookout.net/test/handler/)? What is in your settings when you visit `chrome://settings/handlers`? Can you try clearing existing handlers here and adding them again once you're in Gmail? See [Chrome help](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1382847) for more.

Comment: I don't have any handlers.  I could re-install Chrome - I do that by dragging the icon to trash correct?

Comment: Yes, but often, this is a problem with your profile rather than Chrome itself. When you open Gmail, does it show a "handler sign" in the URL bar on the right?